# How to write a simple image recognition

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have a problem very similar but very much simple than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999920/looking-for-an-image-comparison-pattern-recognition-library).

To begin with I have a small image: [image]

Then I take a screenshot and I want to detect if my small house is in the screenshot.

The problem is that my house can be different in size and slightly different in color.

I've found so far the OpenCV library but it seem quite oversized for my need.

Do you know any simpler library to achieve this task?

Tx

Edit: I've [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118770/opencv-haar-training-for-static-image) about SURF algorithm

Comment: There is no such thing as a simple image recognition problem :) Don't dismiss OpenCV so quickly.

Comment: "Simple" and "image recognition" are contradictory.

Comment: It sounds like you are underestimating how difficult your problem is.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm not denying the difficulty. But it seems to me that spotting a standard picture with just a size deformation should be less difficult than spotting two "eyes" in a video stream?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your question, there will be no sheer or skew to your image as it will be on screen, whereas the problem you referenced is a much more difficult situation. Your image will not experience any distortion, but only an increase/decrease in size.

To match regardless of color, I recommend computing the gradient image (using [sobel kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator))  for both your template image and your screen shot. Now you're matching based on visible edges and take color out of the mix.

To match regardless of size, create multiple versions of your template (the more versions you make the more precise, but the longer the processing) and slide your template across the image until you find an acceptable match.

OpenCV is a beast that has a steep learning curve. If my assumptions are correct, then you are correctly stating that OpenCV is oversized when **simple** image processing techniques can be applied :).