# How can I detect complete body like hand , leg?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, face-detection, cifacefeature

Using [CIFaceFeature](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIFaceFeature/Reference/Reference.html) we can detect face feature. But I want to detect hand and leg too.

How can we detect these? Is there any other classes or logic using which we can detect these.

Comment: Look into OpenCV. iOS' only built in detection class is for faces.

Comment: Good question, +1 from me

Comment: Wait for `CIHandFeature` and `CILegFeature` in iOS 7? I'm joking!

Comment: @0x7fffffff can you provide me best way to install and use open cv, i unable to install

Comment: @P.J have any logic how to do this task.

Comment: @JohnTopley -> haha nice joke..but hope it will be soon

Comment: @Rajneesh071 Sorry, I know what it's for, but I've never used it myself. And don't hold your breathe!

Comment: @0x7fffffff thank for your response.. i am having some problem in installation :(

Comment: reopen this question...

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV is 'just beginning'. Recognition is hard problem and still remain unsolved at most part. There is no hand/leg detection in openCV. You have to train the data yourself using machine learning algorithm provide by openCV. You have to collect positive data (human body image for example) and negative data (non human body image) in order to train.

I suggest to look at this link to speed you up:

1. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/table_of_content_objdetect/table_of_content_objdetect.html
2. [OpenCV haar training for static image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118770/opencv-haar-training-for-static-image)
3. http://kang.blog.com/2009/08/12/how-to-use-haartraining-in-opencv/
4. http://www.technolabsz.com/2011/08/how-to-do-opencv-haar-training.html

Comment: thanks i will check and update you...